# Offset Polyline By Constant

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a polyline that I need to offset by a constant. Imagine a polyline representing the centre line of a highway, I need to offset/parallel this centre line 50 units (to the left and -50 units (to the right) to create lanes.

What function can I use to perform this offset/parallel transation? I believe I should use a `MatrixXd` or `ArrayXd` to store the polyline points? But maybe there is a better object to use to store these? Should I use the method `transpose()` to achieve my parallel operation? Note the polyline points are 2d not 3d.

Comment: The [Clipper](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper/documentation/Docs/Units/ClipperLib/Classes/ClipperOffset/_Body.htm) library can do polyline offsetting beautifully.

Comment: I don't think a transpose or matrix operation is suitable given that the offset at bend points will be along the bisector of the bend angle, which will be different for each bend.

Answer (score 1):

That really depends what else you're going to be doing with the points. You can use a `Matrix2Xd` or `MatrixX2d` as well, if you want to limit the number of rows/columns. I don't know the effects on a polyline but if you just want to add a constant vector to each point, you can do a rowwise or colwise add:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Core>

using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
    MatrixXd mat(5, 2);
    VectorXd vec(2);
    vec << 10., 20;
    mat.setRandom();
    std::cout << mat << "\n\n";
    mat.rowwise() += vec.transpose();
    std::cout << mat << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to calculate the first derivative (tangent) for each point of your polyline. Only then any parallel shift wrt this tangent at a certain point makes sense.